Google signin "Choose Account" does not list Youtube brand accounts in react native?
I want to access brand account while Sign-in with Google in order to create live-streaming on YouTube specific channel in the case of user has multiple channels.
I have used @react-native-google-signin/google-signin for the Google singing in React Native integration with below scopes, but it's not showing specific brand accounts after selecting owner account while login.
And with similar credential web Google Signing flow is working as expected Web Signing Flow
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId:
    'WEB_CLIENT_ID', // client ID of type WEB for your server. Required to get the `idToken` on the user object, and for offline access.
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
  ], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile,
  offlineAccess: true,
});

If anyone have worked in brand account sign in google with React Native please share some insight here.
I'm expecting that google singing should show brand accounts.
Thank you in advance
